# Comparar dos horas (TimeStamp) MySql Java

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

Debo comparar 2 horas una que ya esta registrada de base de datos y la hora actual, me han dicho que puedo usar el [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp) en MySQL hacer que devuelva un verdadero o un falso y los minutos de diferencia, luego en java debo recibir lo que devuelve y según lo que sea realizar un acción. ¿Alguien me podría dar un ejemplo de esto? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes utilizan la función [**`TIMESTAMPDIFF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) de MySQL. Para comparar los minutos:

```sql
SELECT timestampdiff(MINUTE, nombre_columna, now()) <= 120
  FROM tabla
 WHERE otra_columna = algun_valor
```

Devolverá `1` si aún no han pasado 120 minutos o `0` en caso contrario, dependiendo del valor de `nombre_columna` (`TIMESTAMP`) hasta el tiempo actual.

<sup>———————

**NOTA**: Para usar esta función de MySQL en JPA, puede usarse una sentencia de SQL nativa (`createNativeQuery`).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT unix_timestamp( columna ) - unix_timestamp( sysdate() ) AS diferencia FROM tabla;
```

no te va a devlover un verdadero o falso sino la diferencia, pero con eso lo procesas en el java